# ASP.NET MVC 3 DropDownList selectedindexchanged

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

I have a piece of functionality that allows users to filter records based on their own status codes. In the menu, I have a custom filters section:

```
<h3>Custom Filters</h3>
 <br />
   <ul id="ui-ajax-tabs">
      @{ Html.RenderAction("GetGroups", "Manage");}
    </ul>
```

And my partial view looks like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<AllEngage.Model.Group>

@using AllEngage.Web.Helpers

@foreach (var group in Model)
{
    <li>
        <label for="@group.GroupName">@group.GroupName</label>
        @Html.DropDownList("GroupItems", group.GroupItems.ToSelectListItems())
    </li>
}
```

When an item is selected from a dropdownlist, I want an action method to fire in my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(int page = 1, int groupFilterId = -1)
```

What would be the best way to go? Fire using json or perform a post back somehow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass you param to action. The fastes way to do this - pass via query string with the same name as param in action:

```
http://mysite/GetGroups?groupFilterId=2
```

To refresh it you need to send ajax request with param whitch will be fired `onchange` of the dropdown control. Specify some ID for your filter control:

```
@Html.DropDownList("GroupItems", group.GroupItems.ToSelectListItems(), new {@id="ddlFilter"})
```

and then using jQuery make a GET request of your data:

```
$('#ddlFilter').change(function() {
  var queryLink = '@Url.Action("GetGroups")';
  if ($(this).val() != '') {
      queryLink += '?groupFilterId=2';
  }

  $.get(queryLink, function(data) {
      $('#ui-ajax-tabs').html(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use the Url.Action helper instead of harcoding the url in the queryLink var

Comment: Yep, sure. It's just a quick example. I've updated the sample.

Comment: I have a same thing, but my controller actionresult is not refreshing the view. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

you need to fire ajax call using jquery in click event of dropdown.
First chek on click event of dropdown if the value changes then call a jquery ajax call 
I am pasting the code of jquery .

```
 $.get("/Wk/Revision/@hTitle/@pageID/?langID=2", function (data) {
                    $("div#dAjaxContent").html(data);
                    $("div#dShow").css("visibility", "visible");
                    $("#dShow").dialog();
                });
```

// this is for ajax call . the dropdown check do it yourself.
"/Wk/Revision/@hTitle/@pageID/?langID=2"
this will call the controller method revision .
and next i think you will do.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing a post request; you can build one using this:

http://iridescence.no/post/Invoking-ASPNET-MVC-Actions-from-JavaScript-using-jQuery.aspx

You could make an AJAX get request, or if you want to redirect away, you can change the JavaScript's window.location to point to the action you want, as in:

```
window.location = "/MyController/Index";
```