# Dropdown change not calling method asp.net mvc jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

first off I have used this thread to get where I am now but am having difficulty with my situation. [ASP.NET MVC 3 DropDownList selectedindexchanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952547/asp-net-mvc-3-dropdownlist-selectedindexchanged)

I wish to select a value from one dropdown list which will then reduce the available options on a dropdown below it.

Similar to the thread above, I am trying to use jQuery to accomplish this like so:

```
    $('#Park').change(function () {
        var queryLink = 'Url.Action("GetBuildings")';
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            queryLink += '?parkID=' + $(this).index;
        }
        $.get(queryLink, function (data) {
            $b = $('#Building');
            $op = $('<option></option>');
            $b.empty();
            $.each(data, function (value) {
                $b.append($op.attr("value", value));
            });
        });
    });
```

and here is the GetBuildings function in the AvailabilityController:

```
public ActionResult GetBuildings(int parkID)
    {
        var buildQry = from b in systemDB.Buildings
                        where b.ParkID == parkID
                        orderby b.BuildingName
                        select b.BuildingName;
        string temp = "";
        foreach (string b in buildQry)
        {
            temp += b + ';';
        }
        temp = temp.Substring(0, temp.Length - 1);
        string[] buildings = temp.Split(';');

        return View(buildQry);
    }
```

However, when I change the value of the "Park" dropdown, nothing happens.
No change to the URL, which due to the Url.Action("GetBuildings") I assumed would append "/GetBuildings?parkID=2" or something similar.

I'm not sure why it isn't at least doing something as I have made it as similar to the original thread as possible which worked correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it'd be very helpful to see the DropDownList in your view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me this line is the issue:

```
var queryLink = 'Url.Action("GetBuildings")';
```

If you are doing that on the same view you can parse the asp tag by doing (note the *@*):

```
var queryLink = '@Url.Action("GetBuildings")';
```

But i don't recommend that approach, you get get away cleaner than that with a html5 data-attribute

**EDIT:** using data-attribute example.
Add to the dropdown element an attribute like:

```
<select id="Park" data-action-url='@Url.Action("GetBuildings")'>
```

on your js you get the url:

```
var queryLink = $(this).attr('data-action-url');
```

You can also add the parameter to the url by using the $.get data parameter:

```
$.get(queryLink, {parkID : $(this).val()}, function (data) {
```

Comment: I have changed it to '@Url.Action("GetBuildings")', can't believe I left that out... but it still doesn't change anything, the url still doesn't change when the dropdown is changed?

Comment: I was going to look into doing it the better way you suggested but just wanted to get this working before I attempt the new method, assuming it is still something else that is causing the issue

Comment: GET http://localhost:50187/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js 404 (Not Found) Availability:8
GET http://localhost:50187/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js 404 (Not Found)  Availability: 7

Comment: I don't have calls to these in there I have one for 1.4.1, am I using a feature that needs latest jQuery?

Comment: Look at _layout in Views/Shared folder, the references to js and css files are defined there.

Comment: have changed the calls for them to most modern jQuery and modernizr and now receiving the following error from the console...

Comment: http://localhost:50187/Availability/GetBuildings?parkID=function%20(a){return%20a?%22string%22==typeof%20a?n.inArray(this[0],n(a)):n.inArray(a.jquery?a[0]:a,this):this[0]&&this[0].parentNode?this.first().prevAll().length:-1}, now need to start dissecting what's causing the problem here

Comment: `$(this).index` seems rare to me, do you want to get the value? use `$(this).val()` instead. See http://jsfiddle.net/xyUQA/1/

Comment: Yeah I've changed it to .val() now, was just hoping to use the index value to save converting it for the id for the database

Comment: thank you for all your help, going to change around the @Url.Action technique now